# Embedding Facebook Social Like Plugin in Windows 8 Metro app page

Tags: facebook-like, windows-8

Has anyone succeeded embedding Facebook Like button in metro app page? I tried both flavors HTML5 and iframe and none of them seem to be working fully.

What works:
Both flavors can render the not-logged-in version of Like button with total like count correctly.

What does not work:
Clicking on “Like” button takes user to metro IE for sign-in but its unable to return to the metro app page. User stays in metro IE blank page and even if you forcefully come back to metro app and restart, it still does not recognize that you are logged in to facebook.

Has anyone successfully able to add fully functional like button in metro app? Any pointers on what else to try?

Comment: Wow, I've never tried.  I do have the windows8 dev preview installed on a home box.  What url are you specifying for the like button to like?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. You can't integrate js from the outside like you would do on a normal webpage.
Instead you can login to Facebook from a Windows 8 application using OAuth. Once you have a valid access token you can perform any action using Facebook's Graph API, but liking a page is not supported (though the documentation is misleading).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Web Authentication](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122) sample SDK app.

Comment: Fb *likes* can not be posted using web-auth, so the sample you mentioned is useless for me.